# What is the best approach to parse huge JSON file from GCP storage without download

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-storage

I am new to GCP storage. I want to read a large JSON file (2GB array of Objects) from GCP storage in my project (Spring Boot, Java). If I download the whole JSON file, may be I will get out of memory.

So any JSON streaming parsing available to parse without download whole file, like below.

```java
@Component
public class TestA {

        @Value("classpath:/data-array-load.json")
        Resource resourceFile;
        @Autowired
        ObjectMapper objectMapper;
        
        public void processData() {

            int count = 0;
        try {
            JsonFactory factory = new JsonFactory();
            File fileData = resourceFile.getFile();
            ResponseObject classObject = null;
            List<ResponseObject> listData = new ArrayList<>();
            JsonParser parser = objectMapper.getFactory().createParser(fileData);
            if ( parser.nextToken() != JsonToken.START_ARRAY ) {
                throw new Exception( "no array" );
            }
            while ( parser.nextToken() == JsonToken.START_OBJECT ) {
                classObject = objectMapper.readValue( parser, ResponseObject.class );
                listData.add(classObject);
                if(count == 50){
                    log.info("Data size: {}", listData.size());
                    // once 50 , will call another service
                }
                count++;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Sample JSON file will be as below

```json
[
  {
    "id": "345345",
    "info": [
      {
        "data": "info"
      },
      {
        "data": "info2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "456456",
    "info": [
      {
        "data": "info"
      },
      {
        "data": "info2"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "67868678",
    "info": [
      {
        "data": "info"
      },
      {
        "data": "info2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am not getting any best approach to do this. Can any one please guide?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with your code?

Comment: The code I mentioned,  is not working to read from google cloud storage. My question is what is the code to read from a Google cloud storage.

Thanks